# How do i get contacts of askubuntu members?

Tags: support

Having phone contact or address of other members will be useful. How can i get in touch with other members. mail facility will be better option. does this site provide this facility ?

Answer (score 8):

Anyone who wishes to voluntarily share this information can do so in the "About Me" field. However, very few users would be willing to share their phone number or address simply because this is a public website and those are personal details.

As far as getting in touch with other members, many users provide their email address in their profile. (Is this what you mean by "mail facility"?)

Answer (score 4):

Nathan [covered](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13637/1992) this pretty well but I just thought I could add a little two cents extra:

If there is someone you need to correspond with, there are a number of options. Firstly, there is the safe secure method of using the site's own [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). I highly recommend this option, unless of course you require a more private form of communication.

Secondly, you can *ask* the other person(s) you wish to contact if they can be contacted off site, and, if yes, how. Their info, their terms, their time.

As a general rule of thumb however, unless given permission:

**DO NOT EMAIL ANYONE UNPROMPTED - EVEN IF THEY PROVIDE THEIR EMAIL ADDRESS.**

Answer (score 1):

Easy-peasy: Contact details are a two-edged sword: what you do is post your phone and address and e-mail and Skype in your profile and anyone wishing to contact you can then contact you!

:-)